# URL Parameters for Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, url-parameters

I'm attempting to pass radio button values from one form to another using URL Parameters. I can pass values to the url like: `.../?first-name=Joe&city=Dallas` without issue but haven't had any luck with `.../?donation-level=1000.000000`or other similar variables `=yes` or `=1`, etc. I think it has something to do with targeting the radio field properly, but I haven't found a good solution to the problem anywhere.

Here's my form:

```js
  (function($) {$(function () {
    
    //grab the entire query string
    var query = document.location.search.replace('?', '');
    
    //extract each field/value pair
    query = query.split('&');
    
    //run through each pair
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
    
      //split up the field/value pair into an array
      var field = query[i].split("=");
      
      //target the field and assign its value
      $("input[name='" + field[0] + "'], select[name='" + field[0] + "']").val(field[1]);
        
      $("input[type='radio'][name='donation-level']:checked").val(); //something like this for the radio button?

    
    }
  });})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="donation-form-container">      
  <form id="donation-form" class="donation-form" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); collectPayment();">
    <div class="errors hidden"></div>
        <div class="section donation">
            <h3>Make a Donation</h3>
                <div class="field radio 907264 required" >
                    <label for="907264">
                        <input id="907264" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" value="1000.000000"></input><span class="label">$1,000.00</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="field radio 907265 required" >
                    <label for="907265">
                        <input id="907265" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" value="500.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span class="label">$500.00</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="field radio 907266 required" >
                    <label for="907266">
                        <input id="907266" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" value="300.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span class="label">$300.00</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="field radio 907267 required" >
                    <label for="907267">
                        <input id="907267" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" value="100.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span class="label">$100.00</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="field radio other-option required" >
                    <label for="other-option">
                        <input id="other-option" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" maxlength="255"></input><span class="label">Other</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="field tel other-amount" >
                    <input id="other-amount" name="other-amount" class="currency minimum1" type="tel" placeholder="$0.00"></input>
                </div>

        </div>


</form>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean "didn't have any luck with..." ? what is not working? can you explain a little further?

Comment: also your selector `$("input[name='" + field[0] + "'], select[name='" + field[0] + "']")` will return multiple objects since name="donation-level" appears more than once and .val() will only be run on the first returned

Comment: I'm not able to get the radio buttons to select the appropriate value via URL parameter. I'd like to be able to select a radio selection on the first page and carry that value to the donation-level radio buttons on this page's form.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) to handle modifying/getting query params from a url.

What you needed to do is first get the query param value for `donation-level` using urlsearchparams.

Then use a jQuery selector to select all inputs with a attribute `name=donation-level`

Loop through all the inputs and compare the val() of the input to the donation-level value, if its a match, then check that radio button and bail. Below is an example.

```js
var myURLString = "https://www.example.com/index.html?donation-level=1000.000000";

var url = new URL(myURLString);
// or you can do
//var url = new URL(window.location);

var params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
var donationQuery = params.get("donation-level");

$("input[name='donation-level']").each(function(index, elem) {
  var $radio = $(elem);
  if ($radio.val() === donationQuery) {
    $radio.prop("checked", true);
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="donation-form-container">
  <form id="donation-form" class="donation-form" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); collectPayment();">
    <div class="errors hidden"></div>
    <div class="section donation">
      <h3>Make a Donation</h3>
      <div class="field radio 907264 required">
        <label for="907264">
                        <input id="907264" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" value="1000.000000"></input><span class="label">$1,000.00</span>
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="field radio 907265 required">
        <label for="907265">
                        <input id="907265" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" value="500.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span class="label">$500.00</span>
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="field radio 907266 required">
        <label for="907266">
                        <input id="907266" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" value="300.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span class="label">$300.00</span>
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="field radio 907267 required">
        <label for="907267">
                        <input id="907267" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" value="100.000000" maxlength="255"></input><span class="label">$100.00</span>
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="field radio other-option required">
        <label for="other-option">
                        <input id="other-option" name="donation-level" class="required" type="radio" maxlength="255"></input><span class="label">Other</span>
                    </label>
      </div>
      <div class="field tel other-amount">
        <input id="other-amount" name="other-amount" class="currency minimum1" type="tel" placeholder="$0.00"></input>
      </div>

    </div>


  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'll have a look at it!

Comment: Andrew, this seems like an approach that would work well. I noticed that URLSearchParams aren't compatible with IE, which for this client will be an issue. Appreciate the assist, regardless!